# When running a shell script with loops, operation just stops

Tags: linux, bash, shell, for-loop, timeout

NOTICE: Feedback on how the question can be improved would be great as I am still learning, I understand there is no code because I am confident it does not need fixing. I have researched online a great deal and cannot seem to find the answer to my question. My script works as it should when I change the parameters to produce less outputs so I know it works just fine. I have debugged the script and got no errors. When my parameters are changed to produce more outputs and the script runs for hours then it stops. My goal for the question below is to determine if linux will timeout a process running over time (or something related) and, if, how it can be resolved.

I am running a shell script that has several for loops which does the following:

```
- Goes through existing files and copies data into a newly saved/named file
- Makes changes to the data in each file
- Submits these files (which number in the thousands) to another system
```

The script is very basic (beginner here) but so long as I don't give it too much to generate, it works as it should. However if I want it to loop through all possible cases which means I will generates 10's of thousands of files, then after a certain amount of time the shell script just stops running.

I have more than enough hard drive storage to support all the files being created. One thing to note however is that during the part where files are being submitted, if the machine they are submitted to is full at that moment in time, the shell script I'm running will have to pause where it is and wait for the other machine to clear. This process works for a certain amount of time but eventually the shell script stops running and won't continue.

Is there a way to make it continue or prevent it from stopping? I typed control + Z to suspend the script and then fg to resume but it still does nothing. I check the status by typing ls -la to see if the file size is increasing and it is not although top/ps says the script is still running.

Comment: From what I can see (which is nothing), you have no errors.

Comment: Do you get an error? Add `set -x` to the top of your script and see where exactly it fails (this will be a lot of extra output).

Comment: Is the script still in the process list, sleeping? Can you restart the script ?

Comment: No there are no errors, the iterative process simply just pauses and doesn't continue even when I'm debugging. It takes a long time for this to happen though like after 2 or 3 hours

Comment: The script is still in the process list but as I observe it is not actually running. (Compared to what I observe it doing when I first start it)

Comment: It leads me to believe that if a script is running but currently paused, that it will somehow time out. The script is paused when it is submitting jobs to the other machine. When the other machine clears, then submission continues until after about 2 hours then this fluid process stops and is not complete

Comment: To those of you who misunderstood my question I put in a notice in my last edit. I only want to see if someone who has more experience than myself understands linux or shell script enough to know if I should be concerned about a process timing out over time. Some constructive feedback would be appreciated.

Comment: The process will not be terminated just because it hits some time limit.  There are extreme conditions under which the kernel may kill a process, but this is not one of them.  You need to figure out why your process is blocking.  Chances are good it is blocked on IO.  What do you mean by "I observe it is not actually running"?  Do you mean that you see no files being created, or that the status in the output of ps is `?`, or that you have a log message stating "Receive SIGSTOP", or something else?  You have not provided enough information to expect an accurate answer.

Comment: When I say i observe it not running I mean that I no longer see files being created when I type the command ls -la (The file size is not increasing). Is there a way I can verify if it is block on IO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you are using 'Bash' for your script - most likely, you are running out of 'system resources' for your shell session.  Also most likely, the manner in which your script works is causing the issue.  Without seeing your script it will be difficult to provide additional guidance, however, you can check several items at the 'system level' that may assist you, i.e.

- review system logs for errors about your process or about 'system resources'
- check your docs: man ulimit (or 'man bash' and search for 'ulimit')
- consider removing 'deep nesting' (if present); instead, create work sets where step one builds the 'data' needed for the next step, i.e. if possible, instead of:

  step 1 (all files)  ## guessing this is what you are doing
  step 2 (all files)
  step 3 (all files

Try each step for each file - Something like:

```
for MY_FILE in ${FILE_LIST}   
do
  step_1  
  step_2  
  step_3  
done
```

:)
Dale

Comment: Thank you Dale, I understand it's hard not to see my actual script but you provided just the type of answer I was looking for and it was helpful. Much appreciated

Comment: note that if 'performance' or 'time' are important, then after your refine the above, consider using a 'parallel approach' - as long as you are not CPU or IO bound you would quite likely drop from hours to minutes for the run duration...  :)